# Import random Excel into Rails 4 app to create database schema on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

One of my recent Rails app requires import data from excel, I've been following along Ryan's RailsCasts #396 Importing CSV and Excel, it worked out pretty okay, but with one limitation, I have to create the database schema first, just wondering how can I make it more adaptable, so that it could pick up any excel with any header or number of columns, base on the imported the data, to create database schema on the fly. Is that even possible? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational database works well when you know the structure of the data, there are not suitable for making migrations triggered by user data, if you don't know the structure you can always a schema like:

```
MyTable
 col1: string
 col2: string
 col3: string
 coln: string
```

Other approach you may try is to use a non-relational database like mongodb, it's compatible with ruby on rails.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, mongodb is exactly I'm thinking about, haven't used before, looks like this is a good project to start with it.